# SlidingDrawer content stops at previous sibling view

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I've got a view with a `SlidingDrawer` at the bottom. When I open it, it does not open entirely and stops at previous sibling view.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/btn_popup"
            android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#456463" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/featured"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="@drawable/bg_goodidea">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/featured_title"
            android:layout_width="280dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/featured_txt"
            android:layout_width="280dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ViewStub android:id="@+id/menu_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ViewStub>

    <SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content">

        <TextView android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bg_banner_title"
            android:text="banner title" android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#286427" />

    </SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout inflated in the `ViewStub`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_cat_0" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat_2" android:tag="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_cat_2" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/cat_communes"
                style="@style/IconTitle" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat_4" android:tag="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_cat_4" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/cat_hebergements"
                style="@style/IconTitle" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat_3" android:tag="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_cat_3_vide" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/cat_agenda" style="@style/IconTitle" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat_10" android:tag="10"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_cat_10" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/cat_meteo" style="@style/IconTitle" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>       

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put it in a `LinearLayout`. Put it in a `RelativeLayout`, so it can float over top of earlier children.